# php - how to loop a specific sentence in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to repeat this in a variable

`array(array('text'=>$text[$i]),array('text'=>$text[$i+1])),`

how can I do that?

**Code :**

```
public function create_keyboard($text){
    $int = count($text);
    $keyboard_fields = array(
        //** array(array('text'=>$text[$i]),array('text'=>$text[$i+1])), **/
        //i want repeat this here in a loop maybe "for or foreach"
    );
    $reply_markup = json_encode(
        array(
            "keyboard" => $keyboard_fields,
            "resize_keyboard" => TRUE,
            'one_time_keyboard'=>TRUE
        )
    );

    return $reply_markup;
}
```

any body can help?

thanks

Comment: what is `$text` value and what should be the final result?

Comment: use `array_walk` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope it will work

```
 public function create_keyboard($text){
        $int = count($text);
        $keyboard_fields = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$int;$i++){ 
           $keyboard_fields[] = array(array('text'=>$text[$i]),array('text'=>$text[$i+1]));

    } 


  $reply_markup = json_encode(
    array(
       "keyboard" => $keyboard_fields,
       "resize_keyboard" => TRUE,
       'one_time_keyboard'=>TRUE
    )
  );
  return $reply_markup;
}
```